# F# '+' operator overload and List.fold

Tags: f#, overloading, record, operator-keyword, fold

I'm trying to use List.fold on a record type that defines an operator overload for `+`, but I'm getting a type mismatch error when trying to use the `(+)` operator as the lambda passed to fold. Here's a simplified snippet that exemplifies my problem:

```
// a record type that also includes an overload for '+'
type Person = 
    { Name : string; Age: int }
    static member ( + ) (x: Person, y: Person) = x.Age + y.Age
```

the `+` overload works just fine

```
> jen + kevin;;
val it : int = 87
```

but say I have a list of person:

```
> let people = [kevin;jen];;
```

I can't use List.fold to sum all the ages:

```
> List.fold (+) 0 people;;

List.fold (+) 0 people;;
----------------^^^^^^

error FS0001: Type constraint mismatch. The type 
    int    
is not compatible with type
    Person    
The type 'int' is not compatible with the type 'Person'
```

I'm guessing the problem is that F# isn't able to discern the overload of `+` when passed in this fashion, since fold is implicitly typing the list to `int` because I used '0' as the accumulator. I'm not sure if it's possible to get my custom operator overload to work correctly, and if it is possible, what I'm missing to make it happen. (I'm assuming it is possible to make this work because you can use `+` on floats).

### edit

I understand that the problem is the the type mismatch. As JaredPar writes, I get that I could write a lambda to take two person records and add the ages. That's not my point. The issue is that it seems to me there should be a way to get the `+` operator overload I already wrote to be acknowledged by fold as a valid overload.

### another edit

Thanks all for your input. One thing that's becoming clear is that it **isn't** possible to do what I want, but that's fine. I learned something! What I'm seeing is that the resolution of operator overloads is such that they don't work in every context--so with `fold` there is no **seamless** way to make `+` passed as a lambda work just like it would when used as an infix ala `jen + kevin`. It makes total sense why this doesn't work right. The resolutions people have suggested to resolve this problem basically are one-off's to handle the particular issue of `fold`--what I'm really after is how to get the correct operator overload to get picked for **every** situation (i.e. `foldback`, etc)--I didn't want to have to write a bunch of special case code for working over lists. It's pretty clear not what F#'s operator overload resolution has some limitations that make it work to a skin-deep level, which is fine.

Comment: Your `+` member makes no sense. Why would adding two people together return the sum of their ages?

Comment: You've been given quite a lot of good explanations down below. I recommend to try and write the fold function yourself to see why you shouldn't expect it to behave the way you thought it would.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: the example is a STUPID setup to show the principle--it's not what I'm actually trying to do--I made a stupid example to clearly show the issue.

Comment: @Kevin Won - Could you show the code where you think such an operation makes sense?

Comment: @Kevin - I disagree with your conclusion in the "another edit" section.  You can use your `(+)` operator just like the the built-in operator wherever it makes sense and F# will identify and use it without any issues (e.g. `List.map2 (+) [jen] [kevin]`).  The problem in this case is that you are trying to use an `int` seed, a `person -> person -> int` accumulator, and a `person list`, which isn't compatible with how `fold` works.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: you are absoultely right that this use of add makes absolutely no sense. It's too late to go back and try to make an example that would. My point wasn't trying to make a record that makes the + op overload make sense but to attempt to show in a really simple example how the + can't be used in a fold even when you can use it as an infix. I think, in retrospect, that I messed up  entirely with the way I posed my question and framed my example. I didn't make it clear that what I'm after is getting the semantics of the + to work with higher order functions. my bad.

Answer (score 7):

The `List.fold` function takes a lambda / function of type `State -> T -> State`.  The `+` operator in this case has type `Person -> Person -> int` which is incompatible with the signature.  This is why you're getting the error.

To fold the ages try the following

```
people |> List.fold (fun sum p -> sum + p.Age) 0
```

One way to use the `+` operator here as part of the fold is to map the `Person` into the Age property and then use fold against the `int +` operator.

```
people
|> Seq.ofList
|> Seq.map (fun p -> p.Age)
|> Seq.fold (+) 0
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with your solution is that you aren't using the functionality already written in the '+' operator overload. I understand the type mismatch--what I don't want to do is have to rewrite the lambda to do what I already wrote with the operator overload. My question is: is it possible and if so, how?

Comment: @KevinWon it's not possible so long as the operator you wrote is incompatible with the fold function signature. The only way to make it work is if your `+` takes 2 `Person` objects and returns `Person`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a reasonable solution that may be useful for you.

```
type Person = { 
    Name : string
    Age: int 
} with
    static member (+) (x: Person, y: Person) = 
        { Set = Set.ofList [x; y]; SumOfAges = x.Age + y.Age }

and People = { 
    Set:Person Set
    SumOfAges:int
} with
    static member (+) (x:People, y:Person) = 
        { x with Set = x.Set.Add y; SumOfAges = x.SumOfAges + y.Age }
    static member Empty = 
        { Set = Set.empty; SumOfAges = 0 }

let p = [ { Name = "Matt"; Age = 32; }; { Name = "Dan"; Age = 26; } ]
let r = p |> List.fold (+) People.Empty
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is conceptual.  What you pass to `List.fold` is a single function.  It is best to think of `+` as syntactic sugar for a whole stack of different functions - with type signatures like `int -> int -> int`, `float -> float -> float` and `person -> person -> int`.

So what happens when the compiler sees this: ?

```
List.fold (+) 0 people;;
```

So we have a `person` list as well as a default argument of `0` which is an `int`.  So we look at the signature for `fold`

```
List.fold : ('State -> 'T -> 'State) -> 'State -> 'T list -> 'State
```

One way of interpreting this could be `'State = int`, based on the `0`.  So as a result, we need to find an overload of `+` which looks like

```
int -> Person -> int
```

This of course doesn't exist.  You can then use this to come up with a better definition for your `+` operator.  Something like

```
// a record type that also includes an overload for '+'
type Person = 
    { Name : string; Age: int }
    static member ( + ) (x: int, y: Person) = x + y.Age
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this (+) overload?

```
type Person =
      { Name : string; Age: int }
      static member ( + ) (x: Person, y: Person) = { Name = x.Name + " and " + y.Name; Age = x.Age + y.Age }

let jen = { Name = "Jen"; Age = 20 }
let kevin = { Name = "Kevin"; Age = 40 }

[jen; kevin] |> List.fold (+) { Name = ""; Age = 0 };;
```

will return

```
val it : Person = {Name = "Jen and Kevin";
                   Age = 60;}
```

Makes sense?

But seriously, if you feel that finding summary age of a group of people is integral to your `Person` class you may consider making the correspondent static class member `GroupAge` instead of overloading `(+)`:

```
type Person =
  { Name : string; Age: int }
  static member GroupAge = List.fold (fun age person -> age + person.Age) 0
```

and use it when needed as below:

```
[jen; kevin] |> Person.GroupAge
```

Comment: Seems a bit disingenuous to represent multiple people as a type named Person.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Abstracting from the concrete type may help accepting my suggestion; in the end of the day `int` + `int` gives `int`, not `ints` :)

Comment: I suppose I'm getting caught up on the semantic meaning of `+`. Generally it means summation when dealing with numbers and concatenation when dealing with anything else. So in my mind when I apply `+` to two People the result is a set containing the two operands.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Seriously, I'm fully with you on your comment to the original question. Why overloading an operation for the type when for finding age of a group of people `[jen; kevin] |> List.fold (fun acc x -> acc + x.Age) 0` would be good enough?

Answer (score 2):

the problem is than + is defined for add integers,floats,etc  and you define an + for add 2 Persons..but when you try:

```
 List.fold (+) 0 people;;
```

you're trying add an int (0) with a Person (people)
that is!..

actually when you add 2 peoples this return an integer...then everytime than you iterate over people you will get the accumulate (integer) and the people (Person list).....

now..the simple way solve this without add more overloads or generics would be try:

```
[kevin;jen] |> List.fold (fun acc person -> acc + person.Age) 0
```

similar to the example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx

```
let data = [("Cats",4);
        ("Dogs",5);
        ("Mice",3);
        ("Elephants",2)]
let count = List.fold (fun acc (nm,x) -> acc+x) 0 data
printfn "Total number of animals: %d" count
```

...